# Problem inserting data into MySQL db with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm making an app where the user enters data, this data is inserted into a db, and displayed later for other user. The problem is that I don't manage to insert data into the db. I've already made an app with a database, but now it doesn't work. The worst is that I don't get any errors so it connects successfully to the db, it just doesn't insert into the db. The data is sent to the php script from an html form with a POST method.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'mydb';

$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO matches (username, uid, level, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$timestamp = time();
$stmt->bind_param('sssi', $_POST['username'], $_POST['uid'], $_POST['level'], $timestamp);

$stmt->close();
$con->close();
?>
```

Here is some SQL statements to replicate my db:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Generation Time: Apr 06, 2021 at 07:18 AM
-- Server version: 5.7.31
-- PHP Version: 7.3.21

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `mydb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `matches`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `matches`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `matches` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `uid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `level` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Could someone help me, I've been looking for the issues for near two days and it's driving me mad !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You add

```
$stmt->execute();
```

then it should work or show You and error :)

Basically You are preparing query but the query is not executed because You are closing the connection

Comment: Thank you, in my tests, I changed my code several times, and when it wasn't something that caused the problem it was the other...

Comment: @Noé so you admit this was not the real question at all?

Comment: @Your Common Sense as I didn't know what was the problem, I didn't know what the question was, but the answer fixed the problem. I was only saying that I got lost with all my code versions, and my I mixed the lot.